# Trigger not working on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html like this.I am trying to do a jquery trigger on a button click.Basically I just need to close the div when The button is clicked.

I have tried following code in button click using jquery but the div is not closing.Can anyone correct me

JS

```
$('.tags .alert-success .close').trigger(click);
```

HTML

```
<div class="sentiment-text">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="key"></div>
  <div class="text" <div class="tags alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span class="noun">#</span><span class="noun">sed/span> <span class="noun">#</span><span class="noun">menshealth</span>                                                         </div></div>
        <div class="clear-sentiment"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `click` be in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need -- **no space between the first two selectors** -- `.tags.alert-success`. Both `.tags` and `.alert-success` are on the same element:

```
$('.tags.alert-success .close').trigger( 'click' );
//or $('.tags.alert-success .close').click();
```

And close the opening tag of `.text` div so that you have:

```
<div class="text"><div class="tags .......
```

Comment: And valid html syntax `<div class="text" <div clas`

Comment: getting ReferenceError: click is not defined

Comment: I'd use .click() instead.  If you want to stick with .trigger(), use .trigger("click");

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer .

Comment: @PeterKA you forgot to put single qoutes inside click.please do it

Comment: Please refresh your page; the answer was updated a while ago.

Comment: why `.tag.alert-success` both are used? one class is enough as selector. just use `.tags`

Comment: Being a little more specific with your CSS selector is a good idea, @Ritesh.  It requires very little additional processing and makes it less likely that your selector will find extra elements that you don't want.

Comment: @Ritesh, it all depends on the OP's markup; you're right one selector may be enough. However, removing one of them would not have explained why the two were not working together.